# Finding a column within Multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Ho would I refer to a column of Price and Small as Example from Code Below
`

```
dx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Quantity', 'Price'], ['medium', 'large', 'small']])

idx
MultiIndex([('Quantity', 'medium'),
            ('Quantity',  'large'),
            ('Quantity',  'small'),
            (   'Price', 'medium'),
            (   'Price',  'large'),
            (   'Price',  'small')],
           )

df[idx]
```

`

I tried df('Price','small') but honestly a bit new at this and not sure how to refer

Comment: you can find it in the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex)

Comment: Hi Ben - I looked but not sure where in the Doc - maybe just missing it? could you point me to the correct example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a single-level / flat index, the *column coordinate* is a simple string:

```py
df["ColumnName"]
```

When your dataframe columns is a multi-index, the coordinate is an n-tuple:

```py
df[("NameAtLevel0", "NameAtLevel1", "NameAtLevel2")]
```

Follow that pattern, to retrieve your Price-Small column:

```py
df[("Price", "small")]
```

Comment: Thank you - Explains it - Now I feel dumb as usual